# Modify getter without modifying setter in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, getter-setter

So here's what I've done..

I got my class (PFLobby, subclassed Parse Class (doesn't affect something in this case)) which has properties stored as a dictionary (I think so), so they can be retrieved by calling `mypflobbyobject["theattribute"]`.

Here's my code to that class:

```
import Foundation
import Parse

class PFLobby:PFObject, PFSubclassing {

    var channel: String?{
        get {
            return self["channel"] as? String
        }
    }

    var usercount: Int?{
        get {
            return self["usercount"] as? Int
        }
    }

    override class func load() {
        // Register the PFLobby as a PFObject subclass
        self.registerSubclass()
    }


    class func parseClassName() -> String! {
        return "Lobby"
    }
}
```

Now..

On my tableviewcontroller I want to assign the channel.
The compiler says `cannot assign to 'channel' in 'lobby'`.

I want to modify the getter without modifying the setter.

If I write this

```
var channel: String?{
        get {
            return self["channel"] as? String
        }
        set {
            self.channel = newValue
        }
    }
```

I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error..

So how can I modify my getter without modifying my setter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
var channel: String? {
    get {
        return self["channel"] as? String
    }
    set {
        self["channel"] = newValue
    }
}
```